# Video game- two women out to rescue a guy

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I saw an ad for this in a magazine, I think in the early 90's. It wasn't for Nintendo or gameboy systems but it predated Playstation or X-Box so possibly it was a Sega or Turbo Grfx 16 title. It depicted two women in similarly cut but differently coloured costumes, both pointing sci-fi looking guns at the sky in what appeared to be a futuristic urban setting. From what little of the writing on the ad I seem to recall their goal was to rescue a guy held captive from the villains of the game (a rare reversal from the usual video game formulae of the time), unfortunately I don't remember much more than that.

Comment: Is it on-topic for this site? From your description, it is not clear whether there are any SciFi or Fantasy elements in the game.

Comment: Meh, probably belongs on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)... not sure if it can be migrated?

Comment: @J... this would be off-topic on Arqade as there's no screenshot.

Comment: @qazmlpok Fair enough, but a bizarre policy given that the same is welcomed for books, movies, short stories, music, TV shows, etc, elsewhere on the stack.  In fact, their [meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13525/my-game-identification-question-was-closed-as-off-topic-where-can-i-ask-for-hel) explicitly tells people to come *here* to answer these types of questions... so they don't want game identification on their site but they're happy foisting it on other stacks?  That just seems like policy gone wrong somewhere in gamer meta-land...

Comment: @J... You have a point, but every site has their own policy, and SF&F is actually a little unusual as I understand it. Anime, Movies, and Arquade have all either banned identification questions or made it very restrictive. Literature used to have it banned, but returned it, I think in part due to SF&F cross-pollination of users when it restarted. It's still not as popular kind of question. The reasoning has been listed on the Meta of the various sites, but the TL;DR is that identify questions might only be useful to the querent, and seem to attract hit-and-run querents.

Comment: FWIW - movies was plagued with ID questions like "what movie had a blonde kid in it?" and nothing else, which were then never revisited by the asker. We do seem to get at least a few more details, and users that return to respond to comments.

Comment: @qazmlpok It would be appropriate to migrate it, and then let Arqade close it as missing a screenshot, then reopen it once fixed. Seems like it ended up being SF though.

Answer (score 16):

Given that there are probably not all that many 90s shoot 'em ups with female protagonists, I'd hazard that this is Battle Mania (released as [Trouble Shooter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trouble_Shooter) in the US).

[image: US cover art]

It was released in 1991 for the Sega consoles, and had a story where a female combat operative had to rescue a prince from being held hostage.

Here's one if the print ads run for the release:

[image: print ad for Trouble Shooter]

Comment: ^_^ The beams firing off of the ships remind me of Star Trek phasers where, since the actors couldn't see the beams, added in post-production, they emerged from all sorts of angles to ensure they would be hitting what was necessary for the plot.

Comment: This could be it, I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Nu'Daq You're right, it may be one of the many other Sega games depicting _two women in similarly cut but differently coloured costumes, both pointing sci-fi looking guns at the sky in what appeared to be a futuristic urban setting_.